# onKeypress in Vue 3 doesn't capture the last character of number

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, onkeypress, onpaste

I tried to get the entered number in to a function in Vue with the following code.

```
                     <input 
                        type="number"
                        step="1"
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Enter MyLCI number"
                        required
                        min="1000000"
                        @click.prevent="changeSearch(2)"
                        @keypress="searchLeo"
                        @paste="searchLeo"
                    >
```

And my function looks like below.

```
         searchLeo(e) {
            console.log(e)
            const val = parseInt(e.target.value);
            console.log(val)
         }
```

When I type a number in the input field, always the value of the variable "val" comes without the last number I entered. Ex: if I enter 123, it shows only 12.
But when I check the event.target.value from console.log(e) output, it shows the value as 123.

Can someone please, explain the reason.

Comment: Your code does not make sense - you are passing whole event object into `parseInt`

Comment: If you want to do something when the input value changes, you can use the `@input` event to listen for that. With that, you could remove the `@paste` event too.

Comment: It was my mistake Michal. I corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key press is reference to press the button, and the vue doesnt catch the value at that moment. If you change for:

```
<input 
                        type="number"
                        step="1"
                        class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Enter MyLCI number"
                        required
                        min="1000000"
                        @click.prevent="changeSearch(2)"
                        @keyup="searchLeo"
                        @paste="searchLeo"
                    >
```

Your code should works fine, because when you have done the key up, the vue already has it.